# Missing data after reading in df appended with items from paste(x, collapse=";")

Tags: r, paste

At the end of a script, I save many results to a one-line vector and append it to a csv file. One of the results is a one cell string containing collapsed predicted values by semicolons ";". This started to have difficulty when some of the predicted values are negatives (I think), when that happens it simply fails to include all the predicted values. It seems to happen more often when the first value is negative.

With this sample data, it happens to me every time around the 15th or 16th value.

```
#create a blank csv
write.csv(x= data.frame(year=NA, location=NA, side=NA, bias=NA, test_predicted=NA, observed=NA, adj_r2=NA)[-1,], file="Results/my_save_file.csv", row.names = FALSE)

#do this a more than a thousand times
for(i in c(5:1005)){
#dummy data
set.seed(45+i)
test_predic_data <- data.frame(testset=c(1:4), observed=rnorm(mean=8,sd=2,n=80), test_predicted=rnorm(mean=8, sd=10,n=80))
year<-(2016 + i)
location <- "outdoors"
side<-"left"
bias<-0.00658
adj_r2<-0.21

#make negative the begining observation
test_predic_data[1,3] <- test_predic_data[1,3]*-1

#compile results
result_line<-paste(year, 
                   location,
                   side,
                   bias,
                   paste0(test_predic_data$test_predicted, collapse=";"),
                   paste0(test_predic_data$observed, collapse=";"),
                   adj_r2, 
                   sep=",")
#then I save the result line (to my already created csv) by appending it to the #bottom:
write(result_line,file="Results/my_save_file.csv",append=TRUE)
}
```

*UPDATE:* With my real dataset I can check the error by open the csv in Excel (or R code below) and convert the cell from text to data for some weird reason it only has some of the predicted values. Two days ago this sample data was throwing me the error and there were no NA's in the sample data. However today I am not getting the error with the sample data. Maybe I don't know how to recreate the problem. I am running R 3.4.4 on Windows 10.

Checking issue in R after writing the line several times...

```
#read in file
my_save_file_df <- read.csv(file="Results/my_save_file.csv")
library(tidyverse)

#split the results
split_results <-my_save_file_df %>% 
  select(., year, observed, test_predicted) %>%
  mutate(observed = strsplit(as.character(observed), ";")) %>%
  mutate(test_predicted = strsplit(as.character(test_predicted), ";")) %>%
  unnest(.)
```

This error message pops up when there is a problem

```
Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Is there a character limit to the number of items paste0() can work with? Am I running out of memory, do vectors or write.table() have a limit to collapsed items/characters in a single cell?

Comment: You missed creating `location` and `adj_r2` objects in your example

Comment: I can't reproduce this, even when I try to create vectors with negative elements thousands of times, paste them together and split them back into numbers again. Could you have some `NA` values in your data?

Comment: @thelatemail I fixed the spelling error and added the location item. @Marius I added a `set.seed` and it seems to misbehave for me every time. Maybe it doesn't have anything to do with negatives because the last value where it stops saving for me has not been negative, and it only records the first digit of that last value.